# PHP can't count (binary-hex weirdness)?

Tags: php, perl, binary, hex

In Perl I have code that is working correctly:

```
print unpack('B*','10071C2');
```

returns `00110001001100000011000000110111001100010100001100110010`

The code ported to PHP using GMP:

```
function gmp_convert($num, $base_a, $base_b)
{
        return gmp_strval ( gmp_init($num, $base_a), $base_b );
}
$test = "10071C2";
$testb=gmp_convert($test, 16, 2);
```

produces `10000000110110001110000101001101111110110001101110000111`

I thought it might be byte order, however if I use `b*` instead in Perl it still produces something else:

```
PHP---10000000110110001110000101001101111110110001101110000111
PERL--10001100000011000000110011101100100011001100001001001100
```

I simply do not understand this, can anyone help?

Comment: did http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php not work for you?

Comment: I need a binary string not bin data :)

Comment: that's what it does. Input is string, output is string. Also not sure what your perl demonstrator is doing but the hex value 0x10071C2 is 1000000000111000111000010 - confirm this by firing up your calc program, or actual calculator, setting it to hex mode, typing your number, and then asking it for binary. Both PHP and Perl values you show are much larger numbers.

Comment: umm not really, in the docs the hex string is just ASCII values thats why it "prints" it returns a binary string (non printable characters) not `01001101101010` binary representation. the program works as intended : http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html
 difference between b* and B*

Comment: Your perl implementation is not converting a hex number to a binary number. It is converting the ASCII characters to a binary representation of each character's byte.

Comment: please be more specific: do you need the binary string for arbitrary bytecode that happens to, in your example, use ascii-renderable bytes, or do you need to convert a string that represents a hexadecimal number represented as the binary string equivalent instead?

Comment: `print sprintf '%B', hex '10071C2';` to produce `1000000011011000111000010`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Perl and PHP implementations are doing entirely separate things.

The Perl code is converting each of the *characters* from the input string into the binary representation of the ASCII code for that character. For instance, the first character (`"1"`) gets converted into `"00110001"` which is equal to decimal 49, the ASCII code for the character `1`.

Your PHP code [successfully converts](http://ideone.com/8oCHNF) the hex number represented in string form into an equivalent binary representation in string form.

Comment: Oh god.. Im not thinking straight I guess :D Thank You!